# Pandas sort by length of list in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do you sort a pandas DataFrame by the length of the list in a column?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"val1": "a", "val2": [1,2,3]}, 
        {"val1": "b", "val2": [1]}, 
        {"val1": "c", "val2": [1,2]}
    ]
)

df = df.sort_values("val2", key=lambda x: len(x), ascending=False)
```

This results in a `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`

All examples and docs I read use string-length as an example with the key `lambda x: x.str.len()`.
What is the type of `x` in the key function? Shouldn't it be the content of each row in column "val2"?

The result I want is the length of the list in "val2" to be the key to the sorting, resulting in column "val1" having order: a, c, b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `key` method of [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) must be vectorized.

> **key**: callable, optional
>
> Apply the key function to the values before sorting. This is similar to the key argument in the builtin `sorted()` function, **with the
> notable difference that this key function should be vectorized**. It
> should expect a Series and return a Series with the same shape as the
> input. It will be applied to each column in by independently.

You should use [`str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
df.sort_values('val2', key=lambda s: s.str.len(), ascending=False)
```

Or with a custom function:

```
df.sort_values('val2', key=lambda s: [len(x) for x in s], ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
  val1       val2
0    a  [1, 2, 3]
2    c     [1, 2]
1    b        [1]
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually solved the issue. When reading this in the docs (I wrote your solution in my question as well) I didn't even care to try because this is so incredibly unintuitive.

Comment: It's true that having to use the `str` accessor is a bit cryptic ;)

Comment: If you want to use a custom function and if this makes it easier to understand, you could also have used: `df.sort_values('val2', key=lambda s: [len(x) for x in s], ascending=False)`

Comment: Right, so what is the type of the argument passed to the key-callable?

Comment: @vegarab keys needs a callable (function) that accepts a Series and returns a Series. So in you example `x` is the Series (I named is `s` in my answer).

Comment: Is the Series passed the entire series `df["val2"]`? That seems inconsistent with other uses of keys in sorting methods called directly on iterables (the series is iterable)